# Symfony two services in docker configuration

Tags: php, docker, symfony

My goal two services in docker, which have a host(or separate port, how it's should be better approach) and opportunity call each other. At this moment I have simple configuration with twi services on symfony, but only one with virtual host on nginx. And second service not available. How it's should be ?

this what I have

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    build: ./docker/php/
    environment:
      TIMEZONE: Europe/Kiev
    volumes:
      - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
      - ./app:/var/www/app
    working_dir: /var/www/app
    ports:
      - 9002:9000

  sub_app:
    build: ./docker/php/
    environment:
      TIMEZONE: Europe/Kiev
    volumes:
      - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
      - ./sub_app:/var/www/sub_app
    working_dir: /var/www/sub_app
    ports:
      - 9001:9000

  webserver:
    image: nginx:1.11
    depends_on:
      - php
    volumes_from:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  composer:
    image: composer:1.4
    volumes_from:
      - php
    working_dir: /var/www/app
```

docker/nginx/app.conf

```
upstream php-upstream {
    server php:9000;
}

server {
    root /var/www/app/public;
    listen 80;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

and docker/php/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Install recommended extensions for Symfony
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        intl \
        opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-enable \
        intl \
        opcache

# Permission fix
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
```

and what I have 
`http://127.0.0.1:8080/` -> Symfony welcom page from service `php`, from dir `app`

`http://127.0.0.1:9001/` -> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

`http://127.0.0.1:9002/` -> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

docker compose ps

docker-compose ps

```
                Name                              Command               State                Ports            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker-test_composer_1_de8307ec4af2    /docker-entrypoint.sh composer   Exit 0                                
docker-test_php_1_2118a4e10353         docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up       0.0.0.0:9002->9000/tcp       
docker-test_sub_app_1_3c473ac40c77     docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up       0.0.0.0:9001->9000/tcp       
docker-test_webserver_1_b53daccf2f3a   nginx -g daemon off;             Up       443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp
```

in local pc when I check who licten ports

```
lsof -i :8080 -> empty
lsof -i :9001 -> empty
lsof -i :9002 -> empty
```

Comment: Have you tried starting two distinct nginx containers for this? Apparently, you cannot start one instance with two different server configurations

Comment: no, one `webserver` service with `image: nginx:1.11`. I try to create to virtual host for each symfony service

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify where your trying to access the service1 from. So, i'll answer form both the cases:

1. from host,
2. from inside docker

Lets say you installed docker on windows host. In docker-compose for every service you give a port mapping. For ex. for a service named service1 you do

```
service1: 
     ports:
        -9001:9000
```

Here 9000 is the port in the service1 that you want to map. This port is mapped to port 9001 of host windows.
Now you access service1 from windows using -> `localhost:9001`

You access service1 from another service inside docker using -> `service1:9000`

Now, to answer your question, you can do something like following

```
service1:
    ports:
       -9001:9000

service2:
    ports:
       -9002:9000
```

access service1 from host windows -> `localhost:9001`

access service2 from host windows -> `localhost:9002`

access service1 from inside docker -> `service1:9000`

access service2 from inside docker -> `service2:9000`

edit:

try this docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  service1:
    build: ./docker/php/
    environment:
      TIMEZONE: Europe/Kiev
    volumes:
      - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
      - ./service1:/var/www/service1
    working_dir: /var/www/service1
    ports: 
       -8080:80

  service2:
    build: ./docker/php/
    environment:
      TIMEZONE: Europe/Kiev
    volumes:
      - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
      - ./service2:/var/www/service2
    working_dir: /var/www/service2
    ports:
       -8081:80

  webserver:
    image: nginx:1.11
    depends_on:
      - service1
      - service2
    volumes_from:
      - service1
      - service2
volumes:
  - ./docker/nginx/service1.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service1.conf:ro
  - ./docker/nginx/service2.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service2.conf:ro


  composer_service1:
    image: composer:1.4
    volumes_from:
      - service1
    working_dir: /var/www/service1

  composer_service2:
    image: composer:1.4
    volumes_from:
      - service2
    working_dir: /var/www/service2

networks:
  service1:
  service2:
```

Comment: Exactly. Maybe for abit more clarity: You are currently telling nginx to proxy pass traffic to php:9000 (nginx config) which is not a service you define. Traffic to service1 should be routed to service1:<php-fpm-port> and service2 likewise.

Comment: @corvo could you look please nginx config ? I update my question

Comment: @shuba.ivan are you trying to access the services from your host OS?

Comment: @corvo I try to create to virtual host for each symfony service

Comment: @shuba.ivan I have edited the compose file and added a port mapping to both service1 and service2. Now revert back the changes in /etc/hosts and try to access the service1 using `localhost:8080` and service2 using `localhost:8081`. Tell me what happens

Comment: ERROR: for service1  Cannot start service service1: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint symfony-docker-test_service1_1_80ce30fcb50b (880bd409130e380368462e8cb92182f4cfa5a8aeff47af70f2a3ba6aeee52a33): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205611/discussion-between-shuba-ivan-and-corvo).

Comment: it's not help. why services not available by ports 9001 and 9002? Problem with nginx configuration ?

Comment: that means that your services i.e., subapp and php are not listening on port no. 9000. check that they are working and listening on some port and find that port

Comment: looks what showed docker compose, I update my question
`docker-test_php_1_2118a4e10353         docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up       0.0.0.0:9002->9000/tcp       
docker-test_sub_app_1_3c473ac40c77     docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up       0.0.0.0:9001->9000/tcp       
docker-test_webserver_1_b53daccf2f3a   nginx -g daemon off;             Up       443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp`

Comment: @shuba.ivan seems like no one is listening at those ports. Check if your services are up and running.

Answer (score -1):

Your volumes and working dir of `service2` do not match what's in nginx config.

Should be this I guess:

```
  service2:
    build: ./docker/php/
    environment:
      TIMEZONE: Europe/Kiev
    volumes:
      - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
      - ./service2:/var/www/service2
    working_dir: /var/www/service2
```

Also, check the port you expose in Dockerfile.